# json inArray return always -1 jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, push

I want to check if `"foo"` exists in the array named `"Array"`, but `$.inArray` always returns `-1`.  Why does it return `-1` and how do I solve this?

Here is my code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RochesterFox/B5yF2/4/):

```
var Array = []
Array.push({'test':'fuu','url':'sdfsdfsdf'});
Array.push({'test':'qsgbfdsbgsdfbgsfdgb','url':'sdfssffbgsfdbgdfsdf'});
if($.inArray('fuu',Array) != -1) alert('present');
else alert('absent');
alert($.inArray('fuu',Array));
```

Comment: You shouldn't have an Array named *Array*.

Comment: An array should NOT be named as `Array`.

Comment: Answers are already given, so I will add mine as a comment here.  See http://jsfiddle.net/B5yF2/6/ for a fix to your code with explanatory comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'fuu'` is not actually in the array, it's a value of an object inside of the array.  I'm afraid that you need a more complex check.  I would also not use `Array` as the variable name as that's the name of the `Array` object, but apparently it's not a reserved word?  not sure.

```
var arr = [];
...
var found = false;
$.each(arr, function () {
   if (this.test === 'fuu') {
      found = true;
      return false;
   }
});
if (found) alert('present');
```

Comment: To break `$.each`, you need `return false`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills How could you get the objects `index` using this method? So when `this.test === 'fuu'` is true, can we get the objects position in `arr`?

Comment: @Ruddy should be the second argument to the `$.each` callback

Comment: @ExplosionPills Not following you, any chance of a demo?

Answer (score 3):

You are pushing a Hash onto the Array

```
Array.push({'test':'fuu','url':'sdfsdfsdf'});
```

and then testing for a String.

```
$.inArray('fuu',Array)
```

If you add Array.push('fuu') then your test for present will work.